# I have to click the display button twice to render the data to the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In this react component, I want to render the data to the screen when the 'Display' button is clicked by the user, but the button has to be pressed twice for the data to display.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        people: [] // start with empty array of people
    }
    
}
```

Here's my displayData function:

```
displayData = () => {
    const db = fire.database(); // database instance
    const dbRef = db.ref(); // database reference
    var newPeopleArray = []; // new array to push everyone from database into

    dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { // for every child in the data snapshot
            var key = childSnapshot.key; // in this case returns first name
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();

            var newPerson = { // create new person object to push into the array
                name: key,
                age: childData.Age,
                lastName: childData.LastName
            };

            // console.log(newPerson);
            newPeopleArray.push(newPerson);
      
        });

    });

    // set state to the new array of people from the database
     this.setState({ 
         people: newPeopleArray
     });
}
```

And my render() just maps each person in the state with their properties:

```
render() {     

    const stateToRender = this.state.people.map( person => // maps each person in the state to a row in the table
        <div key={person.name}>
            {person.name}
            {person.lastName}
            {p.age}
        </div>
       
    );

    return (
        <div className="container">
            
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <br />
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.displayData}>Display</button>   
            {stateToRender}
 
                         
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbRef.on` is asynchronous code, move the `this.setState` code inside the callback of `dbRef.on`.

```
// set state to the new array of people from the database
 this.setState({ 
     people: newPeopleArray
 });
```

The issue with your original code was execution of `this.setState` before completion of async `dbRef.on`

Answer (score 1):

```
displayData = () => {
    const db = fire.database(); // database instance
    const dbRef = db.ref(); // database reference
    var newPeopleArray = []; // new array to push everyone from database into

    dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        newPeopleArray = snapshot.map(childSnapshot => { // for every child in the data snapshot
            var key = childSnapshot.key; // in this case returns first name
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var newPerson = { // create new person object to push into the array
                name: key,
                age: childData.Age,
                lastName: childData.LastName
            };
            return newPerson;
        });
        // set state to the new array of people from the database
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            people: newPeopleArray ? newPeopleArray : []
        });
    });
}
```